# How to manage an azure local web app file via Git VM

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-machine

I want to manage a file in webapp from a Git repo stored in a VM, I've created a Web App and I need to know if I can relieted it to a git repo stored in a Azure VM.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in 2 ways:

1. Deploy from local Git with Kudu builds
2. Deploy from local Git with Azure DevOps Services builds

The detailed steps are mentioned in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-local-git)